# HABTM Ruby On Rails Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

When i do user.role_ids i get a list of ids like [1,2,3] is it possible to convert these id's into the role.name of that table so it would look like [Developer, Team Leader] Etc?

Do i need something like

```
<td><%= user.role_ids.find_by_name(roles_name.to_s) %></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your question, but how about just:

```
<%= user.roles.collect(&:name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks but is there anyway to make it look like Developer, Corporate instead of  ["Developer", "Corporate"] looks abit messy

Comment: Yes you can append `.join(',')` or even `.to_sentence` to get Rails sugar like **Developer, Corporate and Team Leader**.

Comment: Im new to all this how would i use .join

Comment: No problem, just use `<%= user.roles.collect(&:name).join(', ') %>` and try `<%= user.roles.collect(&:name).to_sentence %>` - it will blow your mind! ;)

Comment: Thanks so much it does this now "Developer, Corporate, and Team Leader" why is there an "," after corporate shouldn't it just be and Team Leader?

Comment: Found it <td><%= user.roles.collect(&:name).to_sentence(:last_word_connector => ' and ') %></td>